# conversion from 2d array to double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to convert a 2d array to a double pointer, I found a solution on stackoverflow, but it does not work, if I do a print it's just gibberish...

I have to do this, because the function I call afterwards needs a const char ** and I can't change it.

```
void test(const char** sl, int n) {

   char s[n][20], t[20];
   int i, j, a;

   for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       strcpy(s[i], sl[i]);
   }


   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (strverscmp(s[j - 1], s[j]) > 0) {
            strcpy(t, s[j - 1]);
            strcpy(s[j - 1], s[j]);
            strcpy(s[j], t);
         }
      }
   }

   char *solutionPtrs[n];
   for (a = 1; a < n; a++)
           solutionPtrs[n] = s[n];

   char **ptr = solutionPtrs;


   printf("\nStrings in order are : ");
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      printf("\n%s", ptr[i]); <-- just not what it should be.

}
```

Can someone tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a mistake here:

```
for (a = 1; a < n; a++)
        solutionPtrs[n] = s[n];
```

Did you mean:

```
for (a = 0; a < n; a++)
        solutionPtrs[a] = s[a];
```